# How large a Matrix has to be not to be able to use Eigen::SimplicialLLT solver?

Tags: c++, system, sparse-matrix, eigen, solver

I have got a sparse matrix that is 10000 by 10000 and the Eigen::SimplicialLLT solver takes 3 seconds, another sparse matrix that is 80000 by 80000 however leaves it hanging forever, with my cpu going pretty hot? Am I using the wrong solver because of the size? What is most suited in this case? I don't know if it's a conceptual mistake or if something else can be wrong. Thanks for any tip.

All matrices come from a discontinuous Galerkin discretization and are symmetric positive definite.

Comment: Try 20000 and 40000.  What happens then?  What other solvers does your library support, and have you tried them?

Comment: How much is the RAM of your PC?

Comment: I am using ubuntu virtual box and I have given 12 GB, but on windows task manager it was using 17 GB while solving, I have 32 GB in total, that might be the case? It managed to solve it but it took a while. Is it normal?

Comment: Did you allocate most of the 32GB to the VM?

Comment: No I have given 12 GB, It was using 17 GB in windows task manager (the extra 5 GB were probably windows or other programs I had open).

Comment: There is no absolute limit, except due to available memory. The latter depends on the structure of your matrix which influences the amount of fill-in. You can try iterative solvers like cg.

Comment: What are the time and space complexities of the algorithm used by `Eigen::SimplicialLLT`?

Comment: I think the larger problem is exhausting the amount of RAM you made available to the VM causing swap to be used in the linux guest OS.

Comment: I switched to using defaulted Eigen::ConjugateGradient and it solves it in a few seconds.